# How to use the value of the variable from "for loop" for mouseEntered?

Tags: java, for-loop, mouselistener

How to get the "i" variable used in "for loop" for mouseEntered inside the panelResult[i].addMouseListener? Thanks!

```
buttonCategory[0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            //hidden codes here...

            panelCategory.remove(scrollPane);
            panelCategory.add(scrollPane);
            panelArray.removeAll();
            panelResult = new JPanel[totalCount];
            int y = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < panelResult.length; i++){

                panelResult[i] = new JPanel();
                panelResult[i].setLayout(null);
                panelResult[i].setBackground(new Color(27, 182, 32));
                panelResult[i].setBounds(0, y, 730, 200);
                panelArray.add(panelResult[i]);

                //hidden codes here...

                panelResult[i].add(labelArrayResult);

                panelResult[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        panelResult[0].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        //if i change it to panelResult[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK); the "i" will be the error. i want to get the value of i from the panelResult[i].
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }

                });

            }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

    });
```

I'm planning to use it as well for mouseClicked and mouseExited. Its a list of result that's why it's all arrayed and looped.

The exception I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at ph.edu.tip.cpedepartment.cpepds.ProjectDesignPage$1$1.mouseEntered(ProjectDesign‌​Page.java:233)
```

Also the number of panels are from the total count from the database that's why i need to use the index. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the exact compiler error you get?

Comment: Instead of that, you should get the MouseEvent and use the `getComponent()` to get the component that you want to change the background color for.

Comment: @Turing85 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at ph.edu.tip.cpedepartment.cpepds.ProjectDesignPage$1$1.mouseEntered(ProjectDesignPage.java:233)

Comment: getComponent() is not :\

Comment: check the edited version with the output program to see what i want to achieve. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the MouseEvent's souce to get the source of the event:

```
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    ((JPanel)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    //the index here is the error
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try :

```
        for(int i = 0; i < panelResult.length; i++){

            //some hidden codes here...
            final JPanel panel = panelResult[i];
            panel.add(labelArrayResult);

            panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    //the index here is the error
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }

            });

        }
```

Comment: Your proposed second solution won't work because just before the for loop, the OP initializes `panelResult` to a new array of JPanel. So the `panel` object returned by `panelResult[i]` will be `null`, and you can't add `labelArrayResult` to it.

Comment: @AaronD I assumed that the JPanels are instantiated in the hidden codes hinted by - `//some hidden codes here...` Of course, I can be wrong, since the current code in the question doesn't even compile.

Comment: My mistake, I see the same code is actually in the question.

Comment: the JPanel[] panelResult is instantiated as a global variable.

Comment: @mushroomgroover that only instantiates the array. Where do you instantiate `panelResult[i]` for each i?

Comment: check the edited version with output of the program :P

Comment: ((panelResult[i])e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLACK); -error

Comment: final JPanel[] panelResult = new JPanel[totalCount]; -error

Comment: @mushroomgroover both of your comments are not what I suggested

Comment: @Eran nahh i get it i'll try again sorry im a bit sleepy~~

Comment: @Eran the first one worked thanks :) but I'll comment down here if there's another complication. Thanks for your patience ;)

Answer (score 1):

The question is, why do you want `i` in the first place? Do you want the actual index value, or do you want the `panelResult` at index `i`? If it's just `panelResult` you want, take Eran's answer.

Otherwise, you can copy the `i` value into a member variable of your listener, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < panelResult.length; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;

        // some hidden codes here...

        panelResult[i].add(labelArrayResult);

        panelResult[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            private int innerI = finalI;

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                panelResult[innerI].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

        });
    }
```

- Only *final* variables can be seen by an anonymous inner class, so I create `finalI`
- Need to remember it for later, so I create `innerI`
- Names of those variables are still free to choose, of course.

Comment: i used "i" which is the index because i'm adding mouse functions to the panels which are arrayed. actually it is functioning when i put an exact value instead of "i" but since i want every panel to function the same thing i would rather use "i" in which it is included inside the for loop ;)

Comment: If all your panels work the same, then I suggest you change your application to make one instance of the listener and give that instance to all panels. Once you can achieve that, your code will use less memory and be easier to read later on.

Comment: i could not give each panel the function like panel[0].addMouseListener because I said awhile ago it is a list and its numbers are based on what is inside the database. Then what if there is added data then I need to code for that added data that's why I used array and for loop so when there is change in the database it also gives the updated result.

Comment: I've also experienced that variables instantiated as global variable can be read inside the mouse functions but if it is a local like in the for loop it can't be and produce error.